# Convert c# code to VB

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am using Math function. The code is below.It is C# code .Please convert it to VB by using CType(variable,type). I tried but it end in vain

```
 iTmpWidth = (Integer)(Math.Floor((double)((double)GridCol.Width /
                                   (double)iTotalWidth * (double)iTotalWidth *
                                   ((double)e.MarginBounds.Width / (double)iTotalWidth))))
```

Please help .

Comment: Sorry but Stack Overflow is not a _code converter_. Best way to conversation is start learning both language and do it yourself.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. [ask]

Comment: I  just tried to print gridview data. The above code is to align margin

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
iTmpWidth = DirectCast(Math.Floor(CDbl(CDbl(GridCol.Width) 
    / CDbl(iTotalWidth) * CDbl(iTotalWidth) * (CDbl(e.MarginBounds.Width) 
    / CDbl(iTotalWidth)))), [Integer]);
```

Comment: Error in Integer. Error Corrections is: change Integer to UInteger

Comment: `CDbl` is not capable of handling `null` , so may throw exception `unable to cast`

Comment: There is no error in CDbl but in last Declaraion Integer